# Unable to load DLL 'DlibDotNetNative': A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed

Tags: c#, face-recognition, dlib, .net-framework-version

When running components using DlibDotNet on Windows Server 2012 I'm getting the following error:

> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'DlibDotNetNative': A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007045A)

The same release build is working fine in my dev machine. I have checked both dev and server machine and both machines have installed Visual Redistributable 2013/2015/2017 x64. Dev machine has Intel Core CPU and the server machine has Intel Xeon CPU.

I am using the 19.18.0.20191202 version of the DlibDotNet Nuget package.

**Updates**:

I have resolved this problem by using an older version which is 19.17.0.20190813. This version working Intel Core CPU as well as Intel Xeon CPU.